# ARIMA with regressions for Hierarchical data forecast

Tags: r, time-series, hierarchical-data, forecasting

I am getting this error when trying to use ARIMA with regressions on a gts object:

> Error in ...fourier(x, K, length(x) + (1:h)) : 
>     K must be not be greater than period/2

Here's a simple reproducible piece of code.  What should I set k to?  I've tried different values but none seem to work.

```
library(hts)
y3 <- ts(matrix(rnorm(300),ncol=60,nrow=5))
blnames3 <- paste0(rep(c("CA", "NY"), each = 30), # State
               rep(c("AL", "LA", "CL", "ES"), each = 15), # County
               rep(c("O", "O", "O", "C", "C"), 12), # Industry
               rep(c("p", "q", "r", "p", "q"), 12),  # Sub-industry
               rep(504:507, 15)) # Product
colnames(y3) <- blnames3

gy3 <- gts(y3, characters=list(c(2,2),c(1,1,3)))

i=5
fc <- forecast(gy3, fmethod="arima", seasonal=FALSE, h=6, xreg=fourier(gy3, K=i), newxreg=fourierf(gy3, K=i, h=6))
```

Comment: Sorry, corrected the code by including i.  gts comes from the hts package - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hts/hts.pdf

Comment: Your time series also needs a frequency attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here. First, your time series contain only 5 observations each which is too few to fit any model for forecasting purposes. Second, you don't specify the frequency of the data in the `ts()` call. Third, you cannot pass a gts object as the first argument to `fourier`().

Here is some code that works:

```
library(hts)
y3 <- ts(matrix(rnorm(3000),ncol=60), frequency=12)
blnames3 <- paste0(rep(c("CA", "NY"), each = 30), # State
                   rep(c("AL", "LA", "CL", "ES"), each = 15), # County
                   rep(c("O", "O", "O", "C", "C"), 12), # Industry
                   rep(c("p", "q", "r", "p", "q"), 12),  # Sub-industry
                   rep(504:507, 15)) # Product
colnames(y3) <- blnames3

gy3 <- gts(y3, characters=list(c(2,2),c(1,1,3)))

i <- 5
fc <- forecast(gy3, fmethod="arima", seasonal=FALSE, h=6,
        xreg=fourier(y3[,1], K=i), newxreg=fourierf(y3[,1], K=i, h=6))
```

Note that the first argument to `fourier` and `fourierf` is only used to determine the frequency and length of the Fourier predictors. So just using the first column of `y3` is sufficient.